# Web View Without the View?

Tags: android

I want my app to interact with my HTML page. Using a scheme and intent filter I can catch links but the problem is how to send things back to the browser.
For example if I want to use my JS function I can use a WebView and call loadUrl("javascript:MyJSFunction(..)
Can I do it with out the view part of the WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `WebView` and set it visibility to `View.GONE`

Like

```
    WebView webView=new WebView(this);
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then

```
       webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyJSFunction(..)
```

Comment: Hi again.I tried it. Just made MyJSFunc to alert something. I see at the LogCat a WARN/InputManagerService Windowalready focused, ignorning...